# Throwing in asp .net WebSite written with c# into ftp

Tags: c#

I've made a WebSite project with asp .net written with c# and I would like to upload my website into FTP. But every guide on YouTube is hosting it locally, I have logins into database, but when I upload my files, it looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLSdH.png

My files look like this in database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkVUV.png

P.S. My server is linux

Comment: You need a specific host that can run ASP. You likely need a DirectoryIndex to the server to actually point to your Default.html (if that's your actual home page).

Comment: Why are you calling what I'm assuming is FileZilla, a database? If your FTP server is just an FTP server then it won't know what to do with an aspx file. Like Farkie said, you need a host that can handle ASP and has the .NET runtime installed.

Answer (score -2):

You Make FTP Server. but you don't have much library in your project.. 
Shortcut If you make code in visual stdio you open a new project not empty project. Then you can delete *.aspx *.master *.ascx or css folder not delete bin file or app_code app_data or *.cs files. You can create *.aspx file and post your ftp server then you can see your project will done.

Comment: So I should just delete all *.aspx *.master *.ascx and it should work? It doesn't, i didnt' quite understood what you mean